# Basic problem that I can not solve

Tags: android, android-emulator

I using Eclipse and the Android emulator. Can someone tell me what is wrong here.

```
//  FILE MainClass.java
    package xxx.yyy;
    import android.app.Activity;
    import android.os.Bundle;
    import android.widget.TextView;

    public class MainClass extends Activity {

        @Override
        public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
                super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
                setContentView(R.layout.layoutA);
    // If this line is enabled, it works fine
            Test1();
    //  but if these lines are enabled, you get FORCE CLOSE
        Class2 c2 = new Class2();
        C2.Test2();
    }

    public void Test1() {
    setContentView(R.layout.layoutA);
          TextView tv = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.DisplayLine);
    tv.setText("Start");
    }
    }
```

---

```
//  FILE Class2.java
package xxx.yyy;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class Class2  extends Activity {
    TextView tv;

//  @Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
      }

 public void Test2 () {
      setContentView(R.layout.layoutA);
      TextView tv = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.DisplayLine);
    tv.setText("Start");
        }
}
```

---

```
//   FILE layoutA.xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<AbsoluteLayout
android:id="@+id/widget0"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent"
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
>
<TextView
android:id="@+id/DisplayLine"
android:layout_width="350px"
android:layout_height="40px"
android:background="#ff99ff99"
android:textStyle="bold"
android:textColor="#ff000000"
android:layout_x="10px"
android:layout_y="10px"
>
</TextView>
</AbsoluteLayout>
```

If  Test1 is allowed to run it is OK.
If  Test2 is allowed to run, get FORCE CLOSE.

Comment: I don't think you can start new activity using object initialization as in Java. Either way, would go as @ASMaitre suggested.

Comment: openup your logcat, and press the circle with E letter. then find out which line is brings error to your code

Comment: As Theresia suggested, you have a lack of understanding of Android. Development on a phone is hard, learning Java by doing Android is harder. I'd advise learning Java first, then moving to Android.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try instantiate Class2 using startActivity instead Class2 c2 = new Class2();

Also, I've noticed that you use c2 and C2 (case sensitive error).

I hope that can help you.

Comment: he is trying to set the layout of Mainclass with the help of Class2.. so there is no need for StartActivity.. For case sensitive thing: he is using eclipse and eclipse with draw a red underline or error mark as soon as he types "C2".

Answer (score 0):

```
Class2 c2 = new Class2();
C2.Test2();
```

Check your capitalization of c2?

Steve

Answer (score 0):

I didnt understand what are you trying to accomplish using this architecture... First of all if you are using **Class2** only to initialize the layout of **MainClass** than you should not extend **Activity** in the Class2.

What i can suggest is this:

```
package com.s;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class Class2 {
    TextView tv;
    Activity activity;

    public Class2(Activity activity) {
        this.activity = activity;
    }

    public void Test2() {
        activity.setContentView(R.layout.layoutA);
        TextView tv = (TextView) activity.findViewById(R.id.DisplayLine);
        tv.setText("Start");
    }
}
```

and for **MainClass** :

```
package com.s;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class MainClass extends Activity {

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);
        // If this line is enabled, it works fine
        Test1();
        // but if these lines are enabled, you get FORCE CLOSE
        Class2 c2 = new Class2(this);
        c2.Test2();
    }

    public void Test1() {
        setContentView(R.layout.layoutA);
        TextView tv = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.DisplayLine);
        tv.setText("Start");
    }
}
```

If you are trying to do something different than this, then please come back with what do you actually want.

Comment: Thanks for the quick response. I used startActivity and it works.